# How to prove limit is equal to infinity?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing

Suppose $f$ and $g$ continuous functions in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$, $c\in [a,b]$ and $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, $x\neq c$. Let $A=\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ and $B=\lim_{x\to c} g(x)$. If $A>0$ and $B=0$ prove that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)/g(x)=+\infty$.

My attempt:
Let $M>0, \exists \delta>0$ such that $0<|x-c|< \delta$, then $f(x)/g(x)=+ \infty$

But I don't know if this is enough to prove the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $f$ you need to find neighbourhood of $c$ where $f(x)>A-\varepsilon_1>0$, for $g$ neighbourhood of $c$ where $0<g(x)<\varepsilon_2 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{g(x)}> \frac{1}{\varepsilon_2}>0$ and then you'll have $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>\frac{A-\varepsilon_1}{\varepsilon_2}$

**Addition:**

1. Let's look at definition of $\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x)=A>0$. As $A>0$, then we can choose  $\varepsilon_1>0$ such that $A-\varepsilon_1>0$. For this $\varepsilon_1$ there $\exists \delta_1>0$ such that in $\delta_1$ neighbourhood of $c$ holds $|f(x)-A|<\varepsilon_1$ so $f(x)>A-\varepsilon_1>0$.
2. From $\lim\limits_{x \to c}g(x)=0$ and $g(x)>0$ we have that for $\forall \varepsilon_2>0$ $\exists \delta_2>0$ such that in $\delta_2$ neighbourhood of $c$ holds $|g(x)|<\varepsilon_2 \Leftrightarrow 0<g(x)<\varepsilon_2$. This is equivalent to $\frac{1}{g(x)}> \frac{1}{\varepsilon_2}>0$

Comment: Thanks, but where those expressions come from?

Comment: I don't understand it very well

Comment: @MarioM21. Wrote addition. Tell, please, if you still have anything unclear.